# WinError 10049 socket won't work with public ip Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ip, public

I was having my first few tries with sockets but I kind of stuck here: 
I really don't understand why sockets will work only with private ip's
here's the code:

```
    import socket
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("12.34.56.78",3307))
    s.listen(5)
```

could you explain me where is the problem?

Comment: What error do you get?  Note IP address should be a string.

Comment: Have you considered looking up error 10049?

Answer (score 0):

First of all (as Mark noted in comment): the IP address should be a string, i.e.:

```
s.bind(("12.34.56.78",3307))
```

Also, if that is the IP address you are actually trying to bind to, it won't work. You can only bind to a local IP address of a network adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in case I would like to connect to the socket from outside my network what would I need to do?

Comment: You need to connect to your public IP address using the port 3307. You can find your public IP address by using a service such as [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/). If you are behind a router with NAT you probably need to configure port forwarding for the port 3307 too, otherwise the router doesn't know where to forward the traffic.